# Gradle build unable to compile when trying to add ads

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, ads

Ok so I am trying to add ads to my application and it tells me to add this line of code in my build.gradle file.

Error image:

[image: Error image]

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```

As you can see in this image at the bottom it says

```
  Failed to resolve:compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
```

I cannot click Install repository and sync project because when I do it does nothing. Does not even open another windows or anything?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

to your project level gradle file

Comment: still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try doing these steps,

**1)Either you are missing maven link**

```
    `repositories {
     maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
           }
     }`
```

**2) Try updating to your google repository in Android SDK**

Start Android Studio -> On the Tools menu, click Android > SDK Manager.
   Update the Android Studio SDK Manager: click SDK Tools, expand Support 
   Repository, select Google Repository, and then click OK.